# Clear form after an ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Well im working on a small php script and i have a problem.
ive made an edits that allows me to post infos in ajax but after the post i want to clear the fields of the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form").submit(function(){
            $.get("response.php", $(this).serialize(), function(a){ 
                $("#info").html(a)
            });
            return false
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `reset()` to reset the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form").submit(function(){
        $.get("response.php", 
        $(this).serialize(),
        function(a){
        $("#info").html(a);
        $('#form')[0].reset();
    })
  ;return false})});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the submit handler you can call `reset()` on the form to set it back to the state it was in on load:

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
    $.get("response.php", $(this).serialize(), function(a){ 
        $("#info").html(a)
        $('#form')[0].reset();
    });
    return false
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Giving blank value to all fields

```
$("#form").find("input[type=text], input[type=password], textarea").val("");
```

If you have checkbox and selectbox also

```
$(':input','#form')
 .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
 .val('')
 .removeAttr('checked')
 .removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

`$("#form")[0].reset();`

or

`document.getElementById("form").reset();`